# How do listen EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a `EditText`. I wamt tp do something, when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while changing `EditText`. How can I do that?

The most simplest method:

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, and how can I compare CharSequence s and Key Enter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sample code for text watcher

```
your_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator());

    private class InputValidator implements TextWatcher {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }    
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {                

        }    
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, create an `OnEditorActionListener` (as a private instance variable, for example):

```
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mEnterListener =
    new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
                /* If the action is a key-up event on the return key, do something */
            }
        return true;
    });
```

Then, set the listener (i.e. in your `onCreate` method):

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(...);
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mEnterListener);
```

Comment: There is an example on how to do this hidden in the `BluetoothChat` sample code as well: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.html

Comment: I'm sorry your method is better. Thanks)

Comment: TextWatcher is more heavy weight, this is the correct answer when listening only to the Enter key.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is:

```
 your_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

       @Override    
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
       }

       @Override    
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count) {

       }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TextWatcher for this purpose. Here is an example on how to work with [TextWatcher](http://tekeye.biz/2012/edittext-attributes-and-textwatcher) and Android [textwatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)  API.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thank you very much. That is a nice decision.

Answer (score -4):

```
your_edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
    }

});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I need to listen key ENTER on the keybord while user type some text in the EditText. I don't care when user will touch  a screen.