# How to override EditText onKey handler, but keep normal EditText behavior

Tags: android, android-edittext, handler

I need to use the content of an EditText field to limit the number of (matching) entries in a listView. For every additional keystroke a new further limited selection of listView entries needs to take place. I have succesfully overridden the onKey handler:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnKeyListener {
    ...
    public View onCreateView(...
        editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    editText.setOnKeyListener(this);
        ...
    }

@Override
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    ...
        handleListViewBehavior();
    }
```

The disadvantage is that I need to implement the behavior of the EditText myself.

What can I do so I can handle the ListView myself, but that the EditText handles it's own behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you should implement standart behavior of the EditText yourself? You attach just a listener, it doesn't touch standart behavior.

Comment: Yes it does. If I type a character on the keyboard, it will not show up in the EditText, because the onKey handler 'eats' the event. I need the onKey to be called, but at the same time I would like to see the typed character to show up in the EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return false, to stop "eating" events.

```
   public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        handleListViewBehavior();
        return false;
    }
```

For explanation read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html).

```
Returns
True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
```

Comment: This solution is even better than using a separate eventhandler class as in 'my answer'. Kudos to csmckelvey and Divers.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the superclass's `onKey()` as the first thing in your method, then apply whatever *additional* operations you want to like `handleListViewBehavior()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKey(view, keyCode, event); <-------
    handleListViewBehavior();
}
```

Beware, I haven't tested this but I think it should help you out.

Comment: I thought it should be something like that, however if I add the line as you suggest, I get a syntax undefined error. 'super' after all refers here to Fragment, unrelated to EditText. But it must be something like that.

Comment: What if you change `super` to `editText`? Can you call the `onKey()` method programmatically like that?

Comment: Maybe I should work with a different event handler, something that does not 'eat' the character typed?

Comment: You may want to look into using an `ArrayAdapter` for your `ListView`.

Comment: gives me the error: The method onKey(View, int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type EditText

Comment: I think you are correct in saying that this approach itself is flawed. I would look for an alternative to this method.

Comment: I am using the ArrayAdapter in the method handleListViewBehavior() method. The challenge however is to trigger this method AND get my typed character into the EditText.

Comment: I will tag this question and when I have time I will come back and try it out in Eclipse to see if I can work something out.

Comment: csmckelvey, if you remove the 'view' argument from your suggestion, the code compiles and text does appear in the textbox, but the behavior is still weird. Backspace, delete, cursor for instance does not work. I'll be back.

Answer (score 0):

The onKey approach was the wrong one. My problem could be solved with this earlier Stackoverflow solution:

[How do listen EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302495/how-do-listen-edittext?rq=1)

EditText keeps it's behavior, but you can still detect keystrokes in the afterTextChanged method.

Thanks to the people for their suggestions!