# create edittext and radiobutton dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, radio-button, checkboxlist

How can i create edittext and radiobutton dynamically  so that either 
  i can write in edittext    or can click the radiobutton  but  i should
  not do the both, and then what ever i have selected or written the answer
  i need to save.

i search  for it but i did not get any appropriate answer , Please help me !

```
RadioButton toggleRadioButton;
    RadioGroup editRadiogroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    editRadiogroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout  editlayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    editlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
         try
      {
      for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++)
         {

    int id = Integer.parseInt(5+ "" + i);
    // add edit text
         EditText editText;
         editText = new EditText(this);
         editText.setMaxLines(1);
         editText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
         editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
         editText.setId(id);
    editlayout.addView(editText, WrapWidth, WrapHeight);
     TextView tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     tv.setTextSize(18);
     tv.setText("Year" +" " +"(or)"+"  ");
     editlayout.addView(tv);

    // add radio button
    toggleRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    toggleRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    toggleRadioButton.setTextSize(15);
    toggleRadioButton.setLayoutParams(new       LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

editRadiogroup.addView(toggleRadioButton,WrapWidth1,WrapHeight);
```

Comment: You could just write "What is your age? (optional)", or have the EditText's hint say "optional". If they don't enter any text, they've declined to answer.

Comment: Actually i can write the answer in edittext or i can simply  decline

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can listen on changes on the Edit text:
[How do listen EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302495/how-do-listen-edittext)

When you get text written in the edit text you can make the toggleRadiobutton dissapear with toggleRadiobutton.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE) or you disable it with toggleRadiobutton.setEnabled(false).

The same if you detect that there is no text in the edittext, you can re-enable the togglebutton.

With the toggleRadioButton you would take the same approach. You check the status of button in on OnClickListener and enable or disable the Edittext accordingly:

```
toggleRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(View v){
    if(((RadioButton)v).isChecked()){
       edittext.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
       edittext.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Juan.....  i did it , instead of using radiobutton i used checkbox and it is working.