# How to know what i am writing in editText at runtime?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

What i want is to know is what i am writing in the edit text at runtime or when i am  writing in the edit text, or else just to know that i have clicked something in the soft keyboard.

I used onKeUp method but its working only if i am pressing enter or cancel button

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.keyCodeFromString():
            if (event.isShiftPressed()) {
                Log.i("sandeep","1");
            } else {
                Log.i("sandeep","2");
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K:
            if (event.isShiftPressed()) {
                Log.i("sandeep","3");
            } else {
                Log.i("sandeep","4");
            }
            return true;
        default:
            Log.i("sandeep","5");
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: use text watcher for this

Comment: More details on TextWatcher at: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher).

Comment: textWatcher a  library or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302495/how-do-listen-edittext

Comment: no method of editext

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543479/6404749

Answer (score 2):

Implement this `addTextChangedListener` for your `EditText`

Add this code in `onCreate()` of your `activity` or `fragment` class

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //do your stuff here
    }

    @Override    
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
});
```

This helps you to find out text has been changed in `EditText` at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `EditorActionListener`

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // use keyEvent
        return false;
    }
});
```